# IIS Application URL Rewrite Issue

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have IIS installed on our Windows Server. I'm trying to do a URL Rewrite for a web application we use internally on our network. Currently the application sits on http://webservices.ourcompany.local/ForkliftInspection/inspection.php

My boss is requesting that the URL be rewritten to http://forkliftinspection.ourcompany.local/inspection.php

Using IIS and the URL Rewrite mod is there any way to accomplish this?

Any help is most appreciated!
Thanks!

Reading the Microsoft guide on using the URL rewrite mod and trying to follow their examples. I'm not having much luck. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, maybe with my capture groups?

([_0-9a-z-]+).([mycompany.local]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-.php]+)

I'm not very experienced with regular expressions but the concept does make sense. I'm just not sure how to apply the process to my current need.

Comment: An AI might be better to answer such intuitive questions. If you do want to learn yourself, make sure you avoid common mistakes https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: I'll read through your article and see if it helps. I'll let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="Remove testapp" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^.*(ForkliftInspection)(.+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^webservices(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="rewrite" url=http://forkliftinspection{C:1}{R:2} appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it didn't work but going to play around with what you suggested and see if I can make it work. I'll let you know if I get it to rewrite correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error messages.

Comment: Hey I didn't see your reply but I will try that 1st thing in the morning! I'll let you know right away. Thank you!